# Constantly getting syntax error after subquery alias (happens with different queries)

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

It's probably something I can't seem to understand with MySQL, but after wasting my day going through StackOverflow's related questions without fixing the issue, I decided to ask about it.

```
SELECT users.idUser, users.name, categoryName
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT `translation` as categoryName 
  FROM localization, 
       usercategories 
  WHERE localization.`string` = usercategories.name 
  AND usercategories.idUserCategory = users.idUserCategory
  ) 
  as Something
WHERE users.idUser != 1 
ORDER BY users.name ASC
```

Whichever query I tried today that would include a subquery, I would get the same syntax error at pretty much the same place: right after the subquery's alias (in this case, `Something`).

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `'WHERE users.idUser != 1 ORDER BY users.name ASC LIMIT 0, 30'` at line 11

Comment: You are missing an `on` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue here is that you're missing the ON clause of your join. You need to select a condition to join the two tables together, like this:

```
SELECT stuff
FROM stuff
LEFT JOIN (other stuff)
ON stuff.something = otherstuff.something. // Add here.
```

Comment: Wow, it's so obvious (sigh)... Sorry guys for the stupid question. It works. Thank you.

Comment: It's not a stupid question,it could have happened to anyone. Perhaps they downvoted it as this was too broad, but I assumed @JeffNoel would understand what I was trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

You could re-organize your query so that it does not need a sub-query. This would also allow you the benefit of adding more columns to the select from any of the tables. Also, it is more correct.

```
SELECT 
    users.idUser, 
    users.name, 
    localization.`translation` as categoryName
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN usercategories ON usercategories.idUserCategory = users.idUserCategory
LEFT JOIN localization ON localization.`string`= usercategories.name 
WHERE users.idUser <> 1 
ORDER BY users.name ASC
```

Comment: I didn't think about writing the query that way. Way easier to read through it. Thank you. I had totally forgotten about the `ON` clause

Comment: Apart from the syntax errors in the OP's attempt there is nothing fundamentally less "correct" with joining on derived tables.

Comment: I would avoid using the sub-query and use the joins as @Plant and I have shown - it is more flexible and readable.

Comment: @MartinSmith I would suggest it is less flexible, less standard, less readable and less maintainable. But that is just my opinion.

Comment: @Donal your rewrite potentially changes the semantics. The OP's originally query left joins onto the result of the virtual two table join which is not always the same as left joining onto the two tables independently.

Comment: @MartinSmith Can you elaborate?

Comment: @MartinSmith ok, so I changed the join to an inner join.

Comment: @donal RE elaboration your fixed version doesn't have the same semantics either. Note there isn't even a row for it in this SQL fiddle result http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/55ad8/8

Comment: (Updated link as typo on first version. Writing queries on SQL Fiddle on mobile not easy...)

Answer (score 1):

You're JOIN criteria is non-ANSI and does not have an ON clause ... perhaps that is causing it? Try this, a bit more optimized:

```
SELECT Usr.idUser AS idUser
  ,Usr.name AS name
  ,UsrCat.translation AS categoryName
FROM users AS Usr
LEFT OUTER JOIN usercategories AS UsrCat
  ON UsrCat.idUserCategory = Usr.idUserCategory
LEFT OUTER JOIN localization AS Lcl
  ON Lcl.string = UsrCat.name
WHERE Usr.idUser <> 1
ORDER BY Usr.name ASC
```

No need for subquery, should be pretty performant.